# How to get the user data on google authentication using JWT bearer authentication?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core

I'm running an angular 2 web app on the frontend. After login with Gmail, I'm sending the token to my ASP .NET Core API on every request for authenticating using JWT bearer authentication. My doubt is how can I access the user info after authenticating the token with google in asp.net core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use JWT events for that. The token returned will contain the user details which can be used.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
                    {
                        ............
                        ...........
                        cfg.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                        {
                            OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                            {
                                ....
                                return;
                            }
                        };
                    });
```